# Which database model is best to use SQL or NoSQL to store/retrieve high resolution media files for broadcast playout?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, nosql

Currently using a SQL Server database to keep records of storage and retrieve of high resolution media files located in several SANs. However, due to several SQL Server databases involved, I'm curious to learn if No-SQL design approach would be best. Thank you.

Comment: Are you storing the media files themselves in SQL (blobs) or just a pointer to the file location?

Comment: Thank you, Russell. Currently pointers to the files location.

Answer (score 0):

NoSQL solutions are great at non-structured or variably-structured information like the layout of a web page, while SQL solutions are better at structured information. The general rule is that if you can fit it into a table structure, use that. Since you're just storing a pointer to a file location I don't think you'll get much by switching data engines, unless you're also storing other information along with the location like a bunch of hashtags that describe the video (for easier searching or "others like this one"). And even then it's probably easier to just have an indexed table of hashtags. If you want to share more information about your architecture the geniuses here can probably give you some pointers.

Comment: Appreciate the info. system is already in operation. Using MS-SQL 2012 DB for record keeping of media file ingest in a 20TB grid. Thanks.